# Print class object content through python function

Tags: python, class

I am reading some threads but i don't understand how do proceed.
I have a function and class as follow. How can I print the class content through the function?

```
def get_address(address):
    resource = 'address/{0}?format=json'.format(address)
    response = util.call_api(resource)
    json_response = json.loads(response)
    return Address(json_response)

class Address:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.hash160 = a['hash160']
        self.address = a['address']
        self.n_tx = a['n_tx']
        self.total_received = a['total_received']
        self.total_sent = a['total_sent']
        self.final_balance = a['final_balance']
        self.transactions = [Transaction(tx) for tx in a['txs']]
```

I tried to `print(get_address('*******************'))`, but this return the object name. Then, adding the following code to the class but it return a tuple which is throw  an error. How can I print all these element correctly?

```
def __str__(self):
        return (self.hash160,
        self.address,
        self.n_tx,
        self.total_received,
        self.total_sent,
        self.final_balance,
        self.transactions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either convert the entire tuple to a string:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str((self.hash160,
    self.address,
    self.n_tx,
    self.total_received,
    self.total_sent,
    self.final_balance,
    self.transactions))
```

or you can use an f-string (or just regular string concatenation) to build your own:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'hash: {self.hash160}, ' +
        f'address: {self.address}, ' +
        ...
```

Note that you may want to also implement `__repr__(self)` by having it just `return str(self)`. Depending on how you try to output the class, this might be necessary.

Comment: It worked! I try to put the class elements into a DataFrame. I don't understand your statement. Could you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` needs to return a string as it's the API that declares how your class instance would be represented as a string. You could throw everything in that tuple into a dictionary and wrap it in a json.dumps() to parse it to a json string.